# Are their tokens for expired memberships?

Tags: civimail, civimember, tokens

We are sending emails to our lapsed members, and would like to include additional data about their memberships.  But all the tokens available seem to refer to "current memberships" (e.g. "latest current membership end date").  If their membership has expired, that's just blank, right?

Is there perhaps hidden somewhere a token for "latest membership end date" (including expired and inactive memberships)?

At the very least, is there a token for "Member since"?  That would be a nice thing to remind our lapsed members about.

If not, maybe someone would like to create those tokens?

I am running CiviCRM Version 5.58.1, on WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

[Fuzion Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/fuzion-tokens) extension has the tokens you want, including Latest Membership End Date.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I actually have Fuzion Tokens installed and enabled.  I can see some of the listed tokens, but not all.

Comment: Possible you have some of the tokens disabled? Check Admin - Communications - Enabled Tokens. If none are checked, they are all enabled, but if only some are checked, only those are enabled.